# How to avoid excessive lambda functions in pandas DataFrame assign and apply method chains

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, pandas, tidyverse

I am trying to translate a pipeline of manipulations on a dataframe in R over to its Python equivalent. A basic example of the pipeline is as follows, incorporating a few `mutate` and `filter` calls:

```
library(tidyverse)

calc_circle_area <- function(diam) pi / 4 * diam^2
calc_cylinder_vol <- function(area, length) area * length

raw_data <- tibble(cylinder_name=c('a', 'b', 'c'), length=c(3, 5, 9), diam=c(1, 2, 4))

new_table <- raw_data %>% 
  mutate(area = calc_circle_area(diam)) %>% 
  mutate(vol = calc_cylinder_vol(area, length)) %>% 
  mutate(is_small_vol = vol < 100) %>% 
  filter(is_small_vol)
```

I can replicate this in pandas without too much trouble but find that it involves some nested `lambda` calls when using `assign` to do an `apply` (first where the dataframe caller is an argument, and subsequently with dataframe rows as the argument). This tends to obscure the meaning of the assign call, where I would like to specify something more to the point (like the R version) if at all possible.

```
import pandas as pd
import math

calc_circle_area = lambda diam: math.pi / 4 * diam**2
calc_cylinder_vol = lambda area, length: area * length

raw_data = pd.DataFrame({'cylinder_name': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'length': [3, 5, 9], 'diam': [1, 2, 4]})

new_table = (
    raw_data
        .assign(area=lambda df: df.diam.apply(lambda r: calc_circle_area(r.diam), axis=1))
        .assign(vol=lambda df: df.apply(lambda r: calc_cylinder_vol(r.area, r.length), axis=1))
        .assign(is_small_vol=lambda df: df.vol < 100)
        .loc[lambda df: df.is_small_vol]
)
```

I am aware that the `.assign(area=lambda df: df.diam.apply(calc_circle_area))` could be written as `.assign(area=raw_data.diam.apply(calc_circle_area))` but only because the `diam` column already exists in the original dataframe, which may not always be the case.

I also realize that the `calc_...` functions here are vectorizable, meaning I could also do things like

```
.assign(area=lambda df: calc_circle_area(df.diam))
.assign(vol=lambda df: calc_cylinder_vol(df.area, df.length))
```

but again, since most functions aren't vectorizable, this wouldn't work in most cases.

TL;DR I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to "mutate" columns on a dataframe that doesn't involve double-nesting `lambda` statements, like in something like:

```
.assign(vol=lambda df: df.apply(lambda r: calc_cylinder_vol(r.area, r.length), axis=1))
```

Are there best practices for this type of application or is this the best one can do within the context of method chaining?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best practice is to vectorize operations.

The reason for this is performance, because `apply` is very slow. You are already taking advantage of vectorization in the R code, and you should continue to do so in Python. You will find that, because of this performance consideration, most of the functions you need actually *are* vectorizable.

That will get rid of your inner lambdas. For the outer lambdas over the `df`, I think what you have is the cleanest pattern. The alternative is to repeatedly reassign to the `raw_data` variable, or some other intermediate variables(s), but this doesn't fit the method chaining style for which you are asking.

There are also Python packages like [dfply](https://github.com/kieferk/dfply) that aim to mimic the `dplyr` feel in Python. These do not receive the same level of support as core `pandas` will, so keep that in mind if you want to go this route.

---

Or, if you want to just save a bit of typing, and all the functions will be only over columns, you can create a glue function that unpacks the columns for you and passes them along.

```py
def df_apply(col_fn, *col_names):
    def inner_fn(df):
        cols = [df[col] for col in col_names]
        return col_fn(*cols)
    return inner_fn
```

Then usage ends up looking something like this:

```py
new_table = (
    raw_data
        .assign(area=df_apply(calc_circle_area, 'diam'))
        .assign(vol=df_apply(calc_cylinder_vol, 'area', 'length'))
        .assign(is_small_vol=lambda df: df.vol < 100)
        .loc[lambda df: df.is_small_vol]
)
```

It is also possible to write this without taking advantage of vectorization, in case that does come up.

```py
def df_apply_unvec(fn, *col_names):
    def inner_fn(df):
        def row_fn(row):
            vals = [row[col] for col in col_names]
            return fn(*vals)
        return df.apply(row_fn, axis=1)
    return inner_fn
```

I used named functions for extra clarity. But it can be condensed with lambdas into something that looks much like your original format, just generic.

Comment: Thank you for the help; I really like the approach. I am wondering what your thoughts are on using `numpy.vectorize` on a function before passing it in; would this be faster than resorting to `df.apply`?

Comment: It probably depends on the function. I would try both and see! The `%time` and `%timeit` magic commands in IPython and Jupyter are great for this kind of analysis.

Answer (score 3):

as @mcskinner has pointed out, vectorized operations are way better and faster. if however, your operation cannot be vectorized and you still want to apply a function, you could use the [pipe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/basics.html#tablewise-function-application) method, which should allow for a cleaner method chaining:

```
import math

def area(df):
    df['area'] = math.pi/4*df['diam']**2
    return df

def vol(df):
    df['vol'] = df['area'] * df['length']
    return df

new_table = (raw_data
             .pipe(area)
             .pipe(vol)
             .assign(is_small_vol = lambda df: df.vol < 100)
             .loc[lambda df: df.is_small_vol]
             )

new_table

    cylinder_name   length  diam    area     vol    is_small_vol
0       a             3      1    0.785398  2.356194    True
1       b             5      2    3.141593  15.707963   True
```

Comment: I like the clean look of this, but it wouldn't be possible to incorporate as a method chain unfortunately. I am assuming the functions are previously defined general functions, which would mean they have to be adapted into a form that takes only a dataframe as an argument. I am OK with that, but find it unfortunate that pandas dataframes don't apply functions in a vectorized way as a default (like in R). I guess these are the rules of the game though. Thank you for your help.