# How to append columns using for loop with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have population data of a city divided into 10 zones. The rate of increase of population is given, I want to calculate the population of each zone for the next ten years and append population for every year in separate columns. I am able to append one column but after that, not able to append the next column using the latest appended column. I am able to append column one by one, which is not a good way to do this

```
data['zone_pop'] = data['zone_pop'].apply(lambda zone_pop: population(zone_pop))
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: You should post a sample of your data as well as the function definition for population. There is likely a way to accomplish what you want with ```groupby``` and ```pivot``` if you provide more detail.

Comment: Sample data will definitely help. You may also benefit from this [Q&A on assign and apply lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61243071/how-to-avoid-excessive-lambda-functions-in-pandas-dataframe-assign-and-apply-met/61243266) Disclaimer: I wrote the accepted answer.

Comment: Please clarify your question. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Zone - Zone_population :
1 - 230624, 2 - 203242, 3 -  228664, 4 - 202753, 5 - 235000, 6 - 233058, 7 - 214049, 8 - 306319, 9 - 356741, 10 - 254557.    For future population calculation, I am simply using compounding formula, Population = Present_population*(1+r/100)^year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `concat` function (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

In the for loop, you should have something like this:

```
    new_data = pandas.DataFrame(population(data[label]), columns=[label_incr])
    data = pandas.concat([data, new_data], axis=1)
```

Where `label` and `label_incr` refer to str variables used to get current year data and new year calculation.

**Edit (detail syntax)**

I guess you have already a dataframe `data` containing a single column 'population_zone' with 10 indexes (for each zone). And the rate of change `r`.

The code above should work (at least, I tested on fake local data)

```
current_label = 'population_zone'
for i in range(1, 11):
    new_label = 'population_zone_year' + str(i)
    new_data = pd.DataFrame((data[current_label] * (1+r/100.)**i).values, columns=[new_label])

    data = pd.concat([data, new_data], axis=1)
    current_label = new_label
```

*If it doesn't work, I probably misunderstood how your data is stored*.

Comment: I tried the pandas.concat, but not able to iterate. Can you please post sample syntax for using for loop with concat